# Three colors repeated

Tags: c#

First i should mention that i am a beginner to C#.

This is the code i have done so far:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= 25; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 1; col <= 39; col++)
            {
                switch (row)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        break;

                }
                Console.Write("* ");                    
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
```

I would really like that the three colors: Yellow, Magenta, Green to be repeated.

The three first sentence are ok, but the rest are green.

And have every other line one step to the right?

All help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Change your code in switch:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= 25; row++) {
                for (int col = 1; col <= 39; col++)
                {
                    switch (row%3)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                            break;

                    }
                     Console.Write("* ");        
                    }
                Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: See also the [% Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int row = 1; row <= 25; row++) {
            for (int col = 1; col <= 39; col++)
            {
                int rowInd = row % 3;
                switch (rowInd)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        break;

                }
                 Console.Write("* ");        
                }
            Console.WriteLine();
```

giving just 1,2,3 rows will assign values for those only. So by using % sign, you will get remainder of row / 3. That is for 3 / 3, remainder = 0; for 4 / 3, remainder = 1; and for 5 / 3; remainder = 2; again 0 for 6 / 3;

Answer (score 0):

Might try something like this:

```
        ConsoleColor[] colors = new ConsoleColor[] { 
        ConsoleColor.Yellow,
        ConsoleColor.Magenta,
        ConsoleColor.Green
        };

        for (int row = 1; row <= 25; row++)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = colors[(row+1) % 3];
            for (int col = 1; col <= 39; col++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```